# multiple tabular columns with asterisk and size

Tags: tables

i would like to use the asterisk along with the * notation like so:

```
r*{5}{c}
```

but with the size variable:

```
r*{5}{l}{1cm}
```

this doesn't work for me though (illegal pream-token).

`r*{5}{l{1cm}}` also does not work.
Of course i can write `r l{1cm} l{1cm} l{1cm}...`, but the asterisk is so much nicer.

What is the correct way of writing this?

Comment: `r*{5}{p{1cm}}` should work (if you load `array`). The `l` specifier doesn't take any argument.

Comment: How exactly should `l{1cm}` work at all? An `l` type column does not accept a width as an argument.

Comment: i was using l to test before i use my custom columntype and didn't realize it takes no argument. Thought its the command thats wrong. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a recent version of array, you can use the `w` columns: `*{5}{wl{1cm}}`